# SQL Server regular expressions clean tags

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2012

I have below HTML content in data:

```
outer text <span class="cssname">inner text to be removed along with tags</span> further text
```

I want to remove all specific tags along with inner text `<span  with class='cssname'`, using regular expression in a query.

The expected output I like is:

```
'outer text further text'
```

Comment: I want someone to write code 4 me.

Comment: This would be better done outside the DB with an HTML Parser prior to insertion of after retrieval.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I wish to do this at SQL db level and not at code side using html parser.  Can anyone help with sql query for this.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions aren't fully supported in SQL Server like in other languages. This will work for a single tag.

```
declare @var nvarchar(256) = N'outer text <span class="cssname">inner text to be removed along with tags</span> further text'

select 
    stuff(@var,charindex('<',@var),charindex('>',@var,charindex('</',@var)) - charindex('<',@var) + 1,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

This way tweaks the HTML to create `<content>` elements from the regular text and casts the result as XML. This is done in the `CROSS APPLY` part.

The second step uses an XQuery to query the text in the `<content>` elements (thus stripping the `<span>` elements).

---

```
DECLARE @tt TABLE(t NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tt(t)VALUES(N'outer text <span class="cssname">inner text to be removed along with tags</span> further text');

SELECT
    stripped=CAST(x.query('for $i in (/content) return $i/text()') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
FROM
    @tt
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            x=CAST('<content>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(t,'<span','</content><span'),'/span>','/span><content>')+'</content>' AS XML)
    ) AS f
```

Result:

```
outer text  further text
```